# Why do you change the index of a power series when you differentiate it?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Why do you change the index of a power series when you differentiate it?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{d}{dx}(-x)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  n(-x)^{n-1}(-1)$$

A slow, dumbed-down explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean differentiate?  That's what I usually call it.

Comment: What happen to the $n=0$ term after the derivative has been taken?

Answer (score 1):

Notice what happens if we don't change the index, we end up with

$$\frac d{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$$

But when we sum it up from $n=0$ to $\infty$, the $n=0$ case ends up as $0$.  And so it is removed from the sum.  Also, you might want to check your result, it doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @MeroFuruya My pleasure.  Cheers!  :)