# Does there exist a function $g(z)$ that agrees with $f(z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

So I was going over old solutions to my homework for my complex analysis course, and we were given the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)z^n$$ which is convergent in $|z|<1$ as the radius of convergence $= 1$ .The question following asked if there exists a function $g(z)$ that agrees with $f(z)$ when $|z|<1$ and is analytic everywhere except at $z=1$. The answer was yes, but the work my prof did doesn't make sense to me. He said yes, and did this, when $|z|<1$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)z^n = (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n)^{'} = (\frac{1}{1-z})^{'} = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$$ but shouldn't we have this instead: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)z^n = (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n+1})^{'}$$ If so how do I go about fixing this issue, or am I understanding the professors work wrong?

Comment: The only difference is that your professor includes the derivative of $1=z^0$.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how are the two summands equal to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you differentiate a power series, you alter the lower bound to omit the previously constant term that is now zero.  Showing this step, and your professor's change of index:
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)z^n  &  &\left[{} = 1 + 2z + 3z^2+\cdots\right] \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} z^{n+1}  &  &\left[{} = 1 + 2z + 3z^2 + \cdots  \right]  \\
&=_{|z| < 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \sum_{n = -1}^\infty  z^{n+1}  &  &\left[{} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \left(  1 + z + z^2 + \cdots  \right)\right]  \\
&  &  &[n \mapsto m-1]  \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m  &  &\left[{} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \left(  z + z^2 + \cdots  \right)\right]  \\
\end{align*}
Of course, since $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}1 = 0$, as was referenced in comments to the Question, these are the same.

The change of index (and why including or excluding the zero doesn't matter) is also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042135/why-do-you-change-the-index-of-a-power-series-when-you-differentiate-it).

Comment: There was more going on that I had considered! Thank you for explaining the steps I see it now!